# What is the difference between ! ( x < y ) and x >= y in C++?

Tags: c++, comparison-operators

Going through EASTL, I stumbled across a peculiar line of code. The following link shows the file with the line number of interest at 1870.

https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/algorithm.h

The code at that line is `if(!(value < *i))`. The comment says that "we always express value comparisons in terms of < or ==" without any explanation as to why this is so. There are also a few other areas where the same comment is placed but without any explanation.

Is there any benefit whatsoever to writing a comparison like that (maybe some context that I am overlooking)? If not, why did the author of EASTL deliberately wrote it in this particular fashion and even took the care to comment about it? Is consistency the only reason here?

Comment: In floating-point, they are different, as comparisons with `NaN` will always return false.

Comment: Sounds like a very specific processor/assembler/compiler type optimization. Is this code targeted at a particular processor/compiler etc

Comment: @AdrianCornish: it has nothing to do with optimizations and everything to do with C++ not defaulting operators in terms of each other.

Comment: Basically it should just mean that EASTL follows the conventions of the C++ standard STL part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means you only need to provide `<` and `==` for container value types. It also means you reduce the amount of variability for those types (as all the algorithms use `!(a<b)` to mean `a>=b` and `!(a==b)` for `a!=b`); otherwise, you could have `>=` and `!=` return inconsistent results.

Answer (score 8):

In C++, you can overload the `<` operator so that it behaves differently than the opposite of `>=`, so they are not guaranteed to be equivalent.

Additionally, in any IEEE floating-point implementation, `NaN < NaN` is false, *but so is* `NaN >= NaN`, so `!(NaN < NaN)` is true even though `NaN >= NaN` is false.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least one difference. If one of the numbers was QNAN (floating-point 0/0) then !(a < b) would've always return TRUE if any of a or b were QNAN, while it would've always returned false for a>=b

Comment: Actually, this behavior is quite annoying. One of the properties of `<`, mathematically, is anti-symmetry. Meaning that `!(a < b)` implies `b < a`. That people consciously chose to violate this property just baffles me, it throws off many an algorithm...

Comment: @SteveJessop: yes, sorry, it's a bit off. The true relationship is: `!(a < b) and !(b < a) => a == b`.

Comment: @Matthieu: True it's annoying, but your definition of antisymmetry is off. Consider `a == b`, then `!(a<b)` doesn't imply `b<a`. So don't use that definition even for types that aren't weird :-) The proper definition is `a < b` implies `!(b<a)`, which in fact NaN does vacuously satisfy since the lhs is never true. The property it misses in respect of `<` is that order-equivalence is not transitive, but `<` on float is a strict partial order.

Comment: I think the justification for the fact that NaN lies outside the defined ordering on floats is that IEEE provides sufficient guarantees that with care you can avoid ever generating one. Don't take square roots of negative numbers etc. If you like you can pretend that all NaN-generating operations have UB, then all you need to worry about is the meaning of NaN inputs to public-facing library functions.

Answer (score 1):

Using just the less-than operator, you can simulate all the other comparison operators. This makes it more consistent and allows you to use a single template parameter when you need to parameterize the comparison. The standard sorted containers and algorithms use `std::less<T>` as the default template comparator for example.

```
operation  equivalent
x < y      x < y
x > y      y < x
x <= y     !(y < x)
x >= y     !(x < y)
x == y     !(x < y) && !(y < x)
x != y     (x < y) || (y < x)
```

For those operations where ordering is not important it's simpler and more efficient to use operator `==` instead.

Comment: The standard library also uses `equal_to (==)` for equality checking.